# Reddit Endpoint for comments for a particular article

Tags: reddit, endpoints

I am trying to get all of the reddit comments for a particular article.

On the Reddit API page, it seems to suggest that:

```
www.reddit.com/r/subreddit/comments/ARTICLE
```

will get me these results (article being a variable), however if I go to an endpoint with the article appended after comments, all I get is a 404 error.

How do you get comments from a specific article via the Reddit API?

I'm doing this in Javascript, but this is obviously a language agnostic question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

reddit's generated API documentation for the [comments endpoint](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_comments_%7Barticle%7D) appears to be incorrect. The correct URL to use to retrieve comments for a post is:

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/{subreddit}/comments/{article ID}/irrelevant_string.json
```

Or for a specific comment:

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/{subreddit}/comments/{article ID}/irrelevant_string/{comment ID}.json
```

The "irrelevant string" can be just an underscore, it doesn't matter - on the website itself, it's a form of the title, but the API doesn't care about the title of the post.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but I'm posting because I found this when I encountered a similar 404 error when requesting the official api comments endpoint, and while the accepted solution works you can still use reddit's generated api documentation [for requesting comments using oauth](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/oauth#GET_comments_%7Barticle%7D).

My error (and I'm guessing OP's too) was not stripping the `t3_` type prefix from `ARTICLE`'s full name. For example,`https://oauth.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/t3_zmvmpn` returns a 404, but `https://oauth.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/zmvmpn` successfully returns the expected comment json.

It's easy to confuse because the official documentation isn't clear on when to use a thing's `name` vs its `id`, but when using the json the `id` field holds the necessary string without the type prefix.

The format when requesting the comments for a given `ARTICLE` (link) is:

```
https://oauth.reddit.com/comments/{id}
```

You can specify the subreddit if you want like in my other examples, but it's not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:
`https://oauth.reddit.com/comments/{id}`.
You need to get authentication pass from reddit first.